# Is it safe to test a float for 0.0 equality?

Tags: comparison, floating-point, double, precision, equality

I know it's dangerous to test floats for equality due to precision errors but is it safe to test for zero? I can think of some cases, for example in optimizing special cases in algorithms, where you would want to do this. The question is regarding floats but I would assume the answer also applies to doubles as well.

Consider the following code:

```
float factor = calculateFactor();
if(factor != 0.0f)
    applyComplexAlgorithm(factor);
```

Comment: I do not accept answers just for the sake of having an accepted answer in my question, there has to actually be an answer that I find answers the question fully.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is safe in the sense that if the value is set explicitly to 0.0f, it will return true there.

It is NOT safe in the sense that you should not expect that the value resultant from calculations will be exactly 0.0f.

So you're really using 0.0f as a special magic value of sorts, not as a real comparison against zero.

Comment: Right, it was a bad example. In this case, what I really meant was to use 0.0f as a special value to compare to, something that would be set explicitly. I don't know why I came up with this example since it's not even what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Understood. However, avoid magic values sprinkled in with "regular" values. They hurt discoverability (as in, when you look at the signature for the function, it's not obvious it is telling you anything other than the factor) and also make it more involved when testing (and using!) the API.

Instead, try to refactor so this condition is exposed as another API or at least it is obvious in the API call (the latter being less useful).

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not safe, because the calculation in `calculateFactor()` will probably not result in 0.0 even through it arithmetically should. A trivial example: (0.4-0.1)-0.3 when done using `double` results in 5.551115123125783e-17

Answer (score 4):

It's certainly *safe*, but you do have to consider what it means for your algorithms. If your algorithm uses `factor` as a divisor (and doesn't check for divide-by-zero itself), then yes, it's perfectly reasonable to check for `factor != 0.0f` before calling `applyComplexAlgorithm(factor)`.

Now, whether or not you should be checking for a value less than some epsilon before using `factor`, is totally up to what your code means and cannot be determined in isolation with the code you've provided.

If (as you alluded to in another comment) you want to use the special value `0.0f` as a sentinel value that means something specific (such as the inability to calculate a factor), then yes, it's absolutely safe to compare using `==`. For example, the following code's use of `0.0f` is deterministic and is never subject to any kind of roundoff error:

```
float calculateFactor()
{
    int phase = moon_phase();
    if (phase == FULL) {  // whatever special case requires returning 0.0f
        return 0.0f;
    } else {
        return 1.0 + (phase * phase); // something that is never 0.0f
    }
}

float factor = calculateFactor();
if(factor != 0.0f)
    applyComplexAlgorithm(factor);
```